# Where are the centered trigonal lattices among the 14 Bravais lattices?

Tags: 3d, solid-geometry, crystallography

I have identified the missing entries in the Bravais lattice table for seven crystal families as the already existing entries int the table. However I'm unable to do so just for the trigonal crystal family. Can you help?

So far, I've done the following.[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no "trigonal crystal family". There is however a *rhombohedral lattice system*, which should take the place of "trigonal" in your table.

All centred rhombohedral lattices are equal to primitive rhombohedral lattices with smaller unit cells.

Comment: Thanks! +1. But can you point me to some resource which can convince me of what you claim (I'm not asking for a rigorous proof!, visuals will do)?